# weird output when typing letter c in shell (non english input)

Tags: shell, character-encoding

I had keyboard set to Georgian language input. Forgot to switch it back to English and typed letter c in shell.

c = ც

english c key is mapped to georgian letter ც - if this makes any difference.

Output baffles me...

What is this?[image]

high res image: http://s27.postimg.org/4uv9crivn/Screen_Shot_2014_04_24_at_12_30_13.png

Target server is ubuntu server 12.04lts.

UPDATE
AS suggested I tried to run `type ც` but when I hit c or copy paste letter ც I get "type .bash_history .bash_logout .bashrc .cache .config .mysql_history .profile .rnd .selected_editor .ssh .subversion .vim .viminfo"

This is how it looks:
[image]

locale produces:

```
sandro@vps:~$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: My guess is that this character, being non-ASCII, as been understood by the terminal as a sequence of characters, at least one of which happened to be a control character. I bet for the Tab character, given the input.

Comment: What happens if you press `Ctrl+V` then `ც`? Or if you run `cat` then press `ც`? Does this happen if you run `bash --norc` (is your shell bash?)? What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a tab (tab+tab in GNU bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see what bytes make up the `ც` character:

```
$ od -tx1z
```

Now type ც and press Ctrl-D (to end your input):

```
0000000 e1 83 aa                                         >...<
0000003
```

(That's the output I get, in a UTF-8 locale).

If `bash` is interpreting that as ASCII with a Meta bit, it may interpret this as `ESC a ESC ^C ESC *`.  Whatever you get seems to reach bash as `TAB TAB`.